# In PhP5 is there a way to get all of my servers IP addresses?

Tags: php, linux, apache, apache2, lamp

Basically I want to load balance downloads over 6+ interfaces. My server is running Apache2 and PHP5, currently I have to manually enter all of the servers ip addresses into the php files array. Is there a way to do it automatically?

For each download link the code currently looks something like this:

```
<?php
$a = array("192.168.2.x", "192.168.2.x", "192.168.2.x", "192.168.2.x", "192.168.2.x", "192.168.2.x"); 
$b = rand(0,count($a)-1);
echo "http://". $a[$b] . "/yourDownload.zip";
?>
```

The server machine has multiple IP's, one for each NIC. The situation here is for a large lan party where we want to distribute files from a main server to all the gamers. Each gamer needs around 20GB of files so serious load balancing is not super important but the ability for the server to be plug and play is. Currently I have to manually enter the IP addresses into the php file itself every time we use a different router or DHCP which takes time and is easily forgotten until it becomes an issue.

In the above code, I would like the array in line 2 to automatically get the IPs of the NICs rather than them being hardcoded.

Comment: This is unclear.  Does the machine running the script have mutliple IPs, or the target machine from which this script downloads files.  It makes a big difference.

Comment: The server machine has multiple IP's, one for each NIC. The situation here is for a large lan party where we want to distribute files from a main server to all the gamers. Each gamer needs around 20GB of files so serious load balancing is not super important but the ability for the server to be plug and play is. Currently I have to manually enter the IP addresses into the php file itself every time we use a different router or DHCP which takes time and is easily forgotten until it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all how you will maintain balance ?
using random function it will not work

Here you have 6 servers so you need to do something work on priority base

code :

```
<?php

$pages = array('192.168.2.1'=>16.66, '192.168.2.2'=>16.66,'192.168.2.3'=>16.66,'192.168.2.4'=>16.66,'192.168.2.5'=>16.66,'192.168.2.5'=>16.66,'192.168.2.6'=>16.66);


function getServerByWeight(array $weightedValues) {
    $rand = mt_rand(1, (int) array_sum($weightedValues));

    foreach ($weightedValues as $key => $value) {
      $rand -= $value;
      if ($rand <= 0) {
        return $key;
      }
    }
 }


$page = getServerByWeight($pages);


echo "http://".$page. "/yourDownload.zip";
```